# CUDA - do I have to allocate and free memory each time?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have a convolution kernel with CUDA which is called very often (it is used for a real time rendering). Should I cudaMalloc and cudaFree each time I want to call the kernel? I tried to store a pointer to the cudaMalloc result and proceed by just cudaMemcpy'ing things before the kernel execution but I experienced weird behavior (like empty memory after the kernel execution)

I was also thinking about using pinned memory but if I have to allocate and free it every time it could even slow the application down. How should I proceed for a kernel which gets called very often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're doing should work.

Maybe you have a bug in your kernel. Try adding cudaThreadSynchronize and cudaGetLastError calls after the kernel launches to debug.

Without more information, I can't offer you any more advice than that.

Comment: Thank you, the cudaGetLastError call helped, apparently I was allocating more threads and blocks than my graphic card could.

Comment: You should put cudaGetLastError calls after all your cuda functions to catch errors from them. When CUDA dies, it dies silently...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no reason to malloc/free for each kernel call. Malloc'ed memory remains valid until you free it. We have lots of code that performs many kernels on allocated memory with and without cudaMemcpy to change the contents in between.

Your problem must be elsewhere. Try to boil it down to the smallest possible example that shows the problem and post the code.